# How to copy object from java ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

How to copy and edit object from arraylist without changing in original list?
This is my test coding...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args){
        Person p = new Person("Myo", 25);
        Person p2 = new Person("Min", 25);
        ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>(); 
         persons.add(p);
         persons.add(p2);
        System.out.println(persons.get(0).getName());

        List<Person> clonePersons = new ArrayList<Person>();
        clonePersons.addAll(persons);
        final Person copyP = clonePersons.get(0);
        /*copyP.setName("Doe");
        copyP.setAge(23);*/

        Person secondCopy = new Person();
        secondCopy = copyP;
        secondCopy.setName("Doe");
        secondCopy.setAge(23);
        //clonePersons.set(0, new Person("Doe",23));
        clonePersons.set(0, secondCopy);

        System.out.println("copy list " + clonePersons.get(0).getName() + " pos 2 " + clonePersons.get(1).getName());

        System.out.println("original list " + persons.get(0).getName());
     }
}
```

result..

> MyoMyo
>   copy list Doe pos 2 Min
>   copy list Doe pos 2 Min
>   original list Doe

Why changes in original list?
Please Help!!

Answer (score 2):

`Person secondCopy = copyP;`

You need to create a new `Person` object, right now you're just assigning the same one to another variable so when you change values the original is modified, too

Comment: But I need to copy object from original one and assign to new arraylist..

Comment: You need to create a **new** object and then assign all the values to it from the original object. Either do it by hand or use a framework like [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

In this case Java is passing the objects by reference, so whatever the number of `list` you'll create you'll working on you two first `Person` instance. 
You need you use the `Clonable` on the `Person`.

Something like

```
class Person implement Clonable {
...
}


List<Person> clonePersons = new ArrayList<Person>();
for (Person p : persons)
    clonePersons.add(p.clone());
```